# two $index in various ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I have two ng-repeat with two "track by index". For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="wheel in car track by $index">
  </div>
</div>
```

The first is $index, is it broke in second ng-repeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this instead

```
<div ng-repeat="(carIndex,car) in cars">
   <div ng-repeat="(wheelIndex,wheel) in car">
   </div>
</div>
```